# Jenkins pipeline script to send customized email

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, html-email

I've been trying to use my customized content for the Jenkins build emails. I got stuck when I am trying to change the contents of html dynamically based on the results from previous stages. I am passing the contents of an html to a variable as below and when i try to access the hash list in that, the value of arrays(key and value of an array) are not getting printed.

```html
  def content = """\
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style=" background-color:lightgreen; width:900px;margin:0;">
<tr>
  <th>Build Results :</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>project Name : </td>
<td>project URL : </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Build Number : ${var3} </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Buid URL :</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table style=" background-color:lightblue; width:900px;margin:0;">
<tr>
<% stagearray.each { item -> 
def key=item.key;
def value=item.value; %>
<td>${key}</td>
<td>${value}</td> 
<% }  %>
</tr>
this is the sample
<tr><td>This is test line </td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to printout  'strategy.size()' and 'strategy.toString()'

Comment: Although variables key and value are defined, getting this error. Couldn't pass the value to html attribute
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: key for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)`

Comment: Looks like you use an array / list collection which won't have elements key and value. You need to use some sort of Groovy map object in this type of iteration. If you have many email formats, consider a pipeline shared library to store the templates as HTML resource files, write a library function to use libraryResource() & load templates by name and populate them from variables passed into the function. I did that and it saved embedding all this HTML in my pipelines - see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps-global-lib/#libraryresource-load-a-resource-file-from-a-shared-library

Comment: Not exactly, when I ran the same within groovy script but not inside html tags, it gives me value of both key and value of an array. Problem is only when we add that variable inside html attributes.